# How to try a file and fallback to another file?

Tags: express

My [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) configuration compiles a `.gz` version of the scripts, though only if the compression reduces the file size, meaning that some `.js` scripts will have `.js.gz` counterpart, some will not.

I am able to tell nginx to try `.gz` in case of `.js` extension. Though, how'd I tell nginx to fallback to `.js` if `.js.gz` does not exist?

```
app.get('*.js', (req, res, next) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line operator-assignment
  req.url = req.url + '.gz';

  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');

  next();
});
```

To complicate things further, I am using [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static).

In [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) I'd be able to achieve this using:

```
try_files $uri.gz $uri @404
```

Comment: Opened an issue on `serve-static`, https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/issues/85.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`express-static` already has everything you need - [`extensions fallbacks`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#extensions):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
  extensions: ['gz']
}));
```

Comment: This doesn't work the way `try_files $uri.gz $uri @404`. `extensions` configuration creates a fallback if file does not exist. It does not try the extension first to see if the file exists.